# Question about $e^T$ where T is a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

First off, I'm given a matrix $A$ s.t. the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p(a) = (-1)^nx^n+x^2-x+2$ and am asked to find $det(A^k)$ for a natural $k$ and $det(e^A)$. So from the polynomial I get $det(A) = 2$, and so $det(A^k)$ has to be $2^k$. Then, by definition, to calculate $det(e^A)$ I expand the Taylor series and get $$\sum_{k=0}^{k=\infty}\frac{2^k}{k!} = e^2$$

Also, in a related question, I'm given a transformation $T:V \rightarrow V$, $V = p_{[x^3]}$ s.t. $T(p(x)) = x\times p'(x) + p(x)$ and am asked to calculate $e^T(1+x+x^2-x^3)$. I proved by induction that $T^k(x^n) = (n+1)^kx^n$. Then, expanding the Taylor series I get  $$e^T(1+x+x^2-x^3) = \sum_{k=0}^{k=\infty}\frac{1^k(1+2^kx+3^kx^2+(-4)^kx^3}{k!} = e + e^2x + e^3x^2 +\frac{1}{e^4} $$

Is this correct? Could I have done anything in a simpler manner? Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: For the first part, the diagonal $2 \times 2$-matrix with entries $2$ and $1$ has determinant $2$ but its exponential has determinant $e^2 \cdot e = e^3$.

Comment: $\det A^k$ is easy because the determinant is multiplicative: $\det A^k = (\det A)^k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for your first question: [$\det(e^{A}) = e^{\operatorname{tr}A}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_determinant_of_the_matrix_exponential) for every real (or complex) square matrix $A$. The trace can be read off the characteristic polynomial.

Your calculation is problematic because you've assumed the determinant of a sum is the sum of the determinants.

**Added**: As for your second question, $T$ is diagonal with respect to the standard basis $\{1, x, x^{2}, x^{3}\}$, so $\exp(T)$ is diagonal with respect to this basis, and the eigenvalues of $\exp(T)$ are the exponentials of the eigenvalues of $T$. In particular, your fourth summand of $\exp(T)(1 + x + x^{2} - x^{3})$ is not quite OK:

> $$\exp(T)(1 + x + x^{2} - x^{3}) = e + e^{2}x + e^{3}x^{2} - e^{4}x^{3}.$$

Comment: So the answer would be $1$? Because looking at the characteristic polynomial, it appears that tr(A) = 0. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To find the trace of $A$ you need to know the size of $A$. You're right that the trace is zero unless $A$ is $(n+1) \times (n+1)$, or else $3 \times 3$ (and $n = 3$).